# Flex Mobile app invocation stopped working

Tags: javascript, android, ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex

From last few months android/ios app invocation get stoppedfor my application.

Following are the code snippets that i am using to invoke app:

JavaScript :

```
window.location = 'myCustomUrl://url'; // will result in error message if app not installed
setTimeout(function() {
   // Link to the App Store should go here -- only fires if deep link fails                
   window.location = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/myapp/xxxxxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8";
}, 500);
```

Android app schema :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:scheme="myCustomUrl"/>
</intent-filter>
```

iOS app schema :

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.myapp.myCustomUrl</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>myCustomUrl</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In Iframe , it also not working.

Please Help,
Thanks!!